# How to scroll a view once it is zoomed in android

Tags: scale, gesture, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Activity layout:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearparent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tulips"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Activity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    enter code here
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout; 
    ImageView image;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontal;
    ScrollView vertical;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearparent);
        horizontal = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        vertical = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.vertical);
    }

    public class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
                image.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
                image.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);

                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.horizontal);
                vg.requestLayout();
                return true;
            }
        }

     @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
         if(ev.getPointerCount() == 2){
             mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
             return true;
         }else{
             Log.d("TOUCH", "dispatchTouchEvent to horizonal");
            horizontal.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            vertical.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

             return true;
         }
    }

}
```

If the image source for the image view is larger in size, then by default it will support scrolling and zooming also. But if the image is small compared to the device screen initially then after zooming am not able to scroll. That is initially there wont be any scroll support as the content is not large and after zooming also the content wont scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The way am scrolling the view once we zoom it is by changing the pivot point. We can achieve the scrolling effect by changing the pivot point according to the user gesture. Please find the code snippet below:

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

```
    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d("EVENT", "ACTION_DOWN");
        startX = event.getX();
        startY = event.getY();
    }
    else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d("EVENT", "ACTION_UP");
        return true;

    }
    else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ){
        Log.d("EVENT", "ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
        startX = event.getX();
        startY = event.getY();
        block_action_move = true;
        enable_zoom = true;

    }
    else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){
        Log.d("EVENT", "ACTION_POINTER_UP");
        block_action_move = false;
        enable_zoom = false;
        return true;

    }
    else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ){
        Log.d("EVENT", "ACTION_MOVE");
        if(enable_zoom){
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        if(!block_action_move){
            Log.d("EVENT", "SWIPE_LEFT");
            if(startX >event.getX() && (startX - event.getX()) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                int[] screen = new int[4];
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                mEpub3RelativeLayout.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
                mEpub3RelativeLayout.getLocationOnScreen(screen);
                if(screen[0] >= (-1*(rect.right - mEpub3RelativeLayout.getRight())) ){
                    mEpub3RelativeLayout.setPivotX((float) (mEpub3RelativeLayout.getPivotX() + ( ( startX - event.getX() ) - SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)*0.2) );
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if(startX < event.getX() && (event.getX() - startX) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                Log.d("EVENT", "SWIPE_RIGHT");
                int[] screen = new int[4];
                mEpub3RelativeLayout.getLocationOnScreen(screen);
                if(screen[0] <= 0 ){
                    mEpub3RelativeLayout.setPivotX((float) (mEpub3RelativeLayout.getPivotX() - ( ( event.getX() - startX ) - SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)*0.2) );
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if(startY >event.getY() && (startY - event.getY()) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                Log.d("EVENT", "SWIPE_UP");
                int[] screen = new int[2];
                mEpub3RelativeLayout.getLocationOnScreen(screen);
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                mEpub3RelativeLayout.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
                if(rect.bottom <= (mEpub3RelativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight()*mScaleFactor) &&
                        screen[1] >= -1*((mEpub3RelativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight()*mScaleFactor) - epub3_reader_parent.getBottom())){
                    mEpub3RelativeLayout.setPivotY((float) (mEpub3RelativeLayout.getPivotY() + ( ( startY - event.getY() ) - SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)*0.2) );
                }else{
                    return true;
                }                    

            }

            if(startY < event.getY() && (event.getY() - startY) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                Log.d("EVENT", "SWIPE_DOWN");
                int[] screen = new int[2];
                mEpub3RelativeLayout.getLocationOnScreen(screen);
                if((actionBarLayout.getBottom() + actionBarLayout.getPaddingBottom()) > screen[1]){
                    mEpub3RelativeLayout.setPivotY((float) (mEpub3RelativeLayout.getPivotY() - ( ( event.getY() - startY ) - SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)*0.2) );
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }

         }
    }

    return true;
}
```